# Do not change mysql column value if request variable is null in laravel eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm, eloquent

I need to check if `$request->link_description is null`  then don't change anything or better to say don't touch the database column value.

is it possible to do so without doing an extra select query?

for example :

```
 /** update ad Seat info */
 $Update_Seat = AdSeat::where('id', $id)->where('owner_id', $owner_id)
 ->update(['seat_name' => $seat_name,
         'seat_url' => $seat_url,
         'logo_src' => ($logo_src) ? $logo_src : null,
         'category_id' => $category_id,
         'plan' => $plan,
         'price_sale' => $price_sale,
         'link_description' => ($link_description) ? $link_description : null,
         'description' => ($description) ? $description : null,
         'income_percentage' => $income_percentage,
         'status' => STATUS_TO_APPROVE]);
```

I mean this part :

```
'link_description' => ($link_description) ? $link_description : null,
```

instead of `null` I want to put something like :

```
'link_description' => ($link_description) ? $link_description : AdSeat::whereId(5)->value('link_description),
```

But as I said before I'm looking for a way to not to run extra select query like above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier to build your data array before hand. Example:

```
// Do not add $link_description here
$data = [
    'seat_url' => $seat_url,
    ...
];

// But add it if $link_description is not null
if (!is_null($link_description)) {
    $data['link_description'] = $link_description;
}

$Update_Seat = AdSeat::...->update($data);
```